# ElasticSearch multiple terms aggregation order

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document structure which describes a container, some of its fields are:

```
containerId -> Unique Id,String
containerManufacturer -> String
containerValue -> Double
estContainerWeight ->Double
actualContainerWeight -> Double
```

I want to run a search aggregation which has two levels of terms aggregations on the two weight fields, but in descending order of the weight fields, like below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_manufacturer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "containerManufacturer",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {"estContainerWeight": "desc"} //Cannot do this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_est_weight": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "estContainerWeight",
            "size": 10,
            "order": { "actualContainerWeight": "desc"} //Cannot do this
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_actual_weight": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "actualContainerWeight",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs" : {
                "container_value_sum" : {"sum" : {"field" : "containerValue"}}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample documents:

```
{"containerId":1,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":12,"estContainerWeight":5.0,"actualContainerWeight":5.1}
{"containerId":2,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":24,"estContainerWeight":5.0,"actualContainerWeight":5.2}
{"containerId":3,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":23,"estContainerWeight":5.0,"actualContainerWeight":5.2}
{"containerId":4,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":32,"estContainerWeight":6.0,"actualContainerWeight":6.2}
{"containerId":5,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":26,"estContainerWeight":6.0,"actualContainerWeight":6.3}
{"containerId":6,"containerManufacturer":"A","containerValue":23,"estContainerWeight":6.0,"actualContainerWeight":6.2}
```

Expected Output(not complete):

```
{
  "by_manufacturer": {
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "A",
        "by_est_weight": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key" : 5.0,
              "by_actual_weight" : {
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : 5.2,
                    "container_value_sum" : {
                      "value" : 1234 //Not actual sum
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key" : 5.1,
                    "container_value_sum" : {
                      "value" : 1234 //Not actual sum
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key" : 6.0,
              "by_actual_weight" : {
                "buckets" : [
                  {
                    "key" : 6.2,
                    "container_value_sum" : {
                      "value" : 1234 //Not actual sum
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "key" : 6.3,
                    "container_value_sum" : {
                      "value" : 1234 //Not actual sum
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I cannot order by the nested aggregations. (Error: Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation...)

For example, for the above sample output, I have no control on the buckets generated if I introduce a size on the terms aggregations (which I will have to do if my data is large),so I would like to only get the top N weights for each terms aggregation.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Could you post a few example docs, and your expected aggregation output for those docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would like to sort the manufacturer terms in decreasing order of the estimated weights of their containers and then each bucket of "estimated weight" in decreasing order of their actual weight.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_manufacturer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "containerManufacturer",
        "size": 10
      },
        "by_est_weight": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "estContainerWeight",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"       <--- change to this
            }
          },
            "by_actual_weight": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "actualContainerWeight",
                "size": 10,
                "order" : {"_term" : "desc"}   <----- Change to this
              },
              "aggs": {
                "container_value_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "containerValue"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I wanted, but isn't there a way to order just a terms aggregation in descending order of the terms ? My problem here is that since the weight fields are double values, the number of unique buckets generated could be functionally infinite(or atleast very large), so I wanted to term aggregate the top x weights (estimated & actual)

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with a few sample values and illustrate the results you are expecting?

Comment: Updated with sample data

Comment: Thanks. Why not simply sorting both aggregations by `{"order": {"_term": "desc"}}`?

Comment: Ok that seems to work. The docs are a bit unclear on this, but does this mean that for terms aggregations, the order by _term is applied only for the particular term being aggregated ?

Comment: The default order is by `doc_count` `desc`, i.e. the terms with the most documents will come up first. Using `_term` instead will simply sort your buckets according to the key of your buckets, in your case the Double weights.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!
I have submitted an edit for your review to reflect the changes in this conversation, once you accept, I will accept your answer